# CURAND properties of generators

Tags: cuda, prng

CURAND comes with an array of random number generators, but I have failed to find any comparison of the performance (and randomness) properties of each of them; mostly, I'd be interested in which generator to use for which application to gain maximum performance. I'd be happy if someone could quickly outline the differences between them or link me a resource that does so.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This picture shows the performance for different RNGs.

[image: Speed of cuRAND RNGs]

For randomness, it should be only related to the RNG type/algorithm. So you can refer to Intel MKL doc. There's detail info and research papers in it. The type names in both CURAND and MKL are very similar.

http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/mklman/GUID-3D7D2650-A414-4C95-AF33-BE291BAB2AC3.htm

Comment: Ah, okay, I thought there was more to under what circumstances which of them performed better. I can see how curandStateMRG32k3a is convenient because you only need one per 256 threads, I thought the others had similar properties.

Answer (score 3):

First difference is efficiency. XORWOW is default generator, but isn't always most efficient. For instance, Philox is faster for generating normally distributed floats.

[image: cuRAND]

Another difference is, that in practice You can generate more than one float with each call with some generators.
For example, with Philox You can generate even 4 floats normally or uniformly distributed with each call, while with XORWOW you can generate max two floats normally or uniformly distributed.

```
__device__ float4 
curand_normal4 (curandStatePhilox4_32_10_t *state)
```

Next difference is period of pseudorandom sequence (Total state space of the PRNG before 
you start to see repeats). Xorwow has period about 2^190 (with the state set up after 2^67 for the same seed)*. For Philox, subsequence and offset together define offset in a sequence with period 2^128.
Note that if You run millions of threads with the same seed You could run out of state space per thread and start seeing repeats. ((2^190) / (10^6)) / (2^67) = 1.0633824 × 10^31

One more difference is size of the states. For Xorwow sizeof(curandState_t) is 48 bytes and sizeof(curandStatePhilox4_32_10_t) is 64 bytes.
When You run millions of threads (each thread has its own curand state) you can run out of device memory. 1024^2*64 ~= 64 megabytes per million threads.

XORWOW, Philox, MRR32k3a, MTGP32 are Pseudo-random generators while both Sobols are Quasi-ranom generators.

*When calling curand_init with a seed, it scrambles that seed and then skips ahead 2^67 numbers (this is kind of expensive but has some nice properties)

sources:
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuRAND
http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs195v/lecture/week11.pdf